# SQL: How to Auto-increment a value in the database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i am creating a custom CustomerID by getting the first double characters of first name and last name taken from textboxes as following:

```
 string CustomID = (FirstNameTxtbox.Value.Substring(0, 2) + LastNametxtbox.Value.Substring(0, 2));
```

in order to avoid a Duplicated CustomerID
i am trying to:

get the 5th value which is the int since the first 4 values are characters. and then increase it by 1.

my attempt:

```
string s =  cmd.CommandText= " Select MAX(CustomerID) from Customers";
string CustomID = (FirstNameTxtbox.Value.Substring(0, 2) + LastNametxtbox.Value.Substring(0, 2) + (Convert.ToInt32(s)+1)) ;
```

example:

First name= Mak
last name = shima

CustomerID = MASH1

next value will be e.g KAAR2

Comment: I would _strongly_ recommend not to use other data to generate a PK.  What happens if you need to change the first or last name?  Why not use a numeric auto-incrementing key?

Comment: @DStanley then i will create an update sql statement with the new PK (customerID).

Comment: What about dependent tables?  You'd need to turn off all referential integrity, update the PK on the main table and all dependent tables, then turn RI back on.  Seems like a lot of trouble to have a "smart" primary key.

Comment: @DStanley so instead, change The CustomerID to a non primary key and do the increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the primary key an auto increment integer and the `CustomerID` is a string that is computed based on the `ID`, this way it will never duplicate.

You can set the `CustomerID` by:

1. Computed Field based on the auto increment `ID`
2. Trigger that fires on insert and set the `CustomerID`
3. Custom Code in your back-end, add the customer object, retrieve the primary key and set the `CustomerID`

Your `CustomerID` can be something like `0000001`.

ex: First customer will have a primary key of 1, the `CustomerID` will be `000001`, next customer will be `000002` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Your practice is not recommended, you should design a primary key with Auto Increment small value like integer, remember that the table is physically sorted on the clustered index (your primary key), and your non-clustered indexes are keyed based on your primary key.

You can add your combined value in another field if you still need it, and if your queries are based on it, create a non clustered index for it.

Comment: While I agree with your comment, the primary key is not always the clustered index.

Comment: but how do i get the 5th value from the database and increment it ?

Comment: @Makishima can you provide sample of what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @Makishima you don't increment it, you leave the value blank when you insert in to the database and the database figures out the value for you. You can then read the value back out it just assigned if you need the value as a foreign key for other rows.

Comment: @Yaman i updated, i think the question is now how to auto increment a varchar value ?!?!

Comment: @Makishima You can do it by converting to a number. using CAST or CONVERT and then add 1, or in your application, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @Yaman well, i did it in a different way, i made the customerID a non-primary key and created id (pk) that is auto incremented using identity (1,1) and so i assigned my customer ID to be first double characters plus the relevant id value. Not sure if this is a good practice tho. what do you think ?

Comment: @Makishima It's not bad, but preferably use int rather than concatenated string, check performance on a big sample, u might see a difference

Answer (score 0):

Yes Primary key (id)  is necessary but Customer ID can be Custom String like  'anything'.

I you want to generate Customer ID like this

*First name= Mak

last name = shima

CustomerID = MASH1

next value will be e.g KAAR2*

Use front end to generate  KA(first)AR(last)+Sequence in Sql Server /Oracle.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[CustomerId_Generation] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE 
GO
```

Get value of sequence and Add to database afterward.

There was a case that Same **CutomerID** for returning customer than i mean repetitive same   **CutomerID** can also be handled by your code if you follow this approach.